# WebSocketException: Connection was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: dart, server, puppeteer

I am currently trying to work with the [Dart Puppeteer library](https://github.com/xvrh/puppeteer-dart). I have been running the following piece of code:

```
  var browser = await puppeteer.connect(browserWsEndpoint: "wss://chrome.browserless.io");
```

Unfortunately when I do run this, I get the following error:

> WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://chrome.browserless.io:0#' was not upgraded to websocket

I was wondering how i could go about fixing this? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with Browserless rather than any Dart code on that certain day. I tried it later and it worked flawlessly.